# Spring MVC testing results in 415 error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to write integration tests for my REST API implemented with Spring MVC.

Here is my REST implementation:

```
import org.myproject.api.input.ProjectInput;
import org.myproject.dao.ProjectsDao;
import org.myproject.model.Project;
import org.myproject.model.Projects;
import org.myproject.util.Exceptions;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/projects")
public class ProjectsApi {

    @Autowired
    private ProjectsDao projectsDao;

    ...

    @RequestMapping(value = "/",
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        produces = {"application/json"},
        consumes = {"application/json"})
    public @ResponseBody Project addProject(@RequestBody ProjectInput projectInput) throws IOException {
        logger.info("Add project");
        Project project = projectInput.createProject();
        projectsDao.add(project);

        return project;
     }
}
```

Here is ProjectInput class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class ProjectInput {
    private String name;
    private String description;

    // Constructor to make JSON converter happy
    private ProjectInput() {}

    public ProjectInput(String name, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

And here is my test:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.openboard.api.input.ProjectInput;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath*:applicationContext.xml"})
public class TestProjectsApi {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddProject() throws Exception {
        ProjectInput input = new ProjectInput("name", "description");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(input);
        // json value is: {"name":"name","description":"description"}

        mockMvc.perform(post("/projects/")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(json.getBytes()))
        .andDo(print())
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I receive the following error:

```
org.myproject.api.TestProjectsApi > testAddProject FAILED
    java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<415>
        at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:60)
        at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:89)
        at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers$10.match(StatusResultMatchers.java:653)
        at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:152)
        at org.myproject.api.TestProjectsApi.testAddProject(TestProjectsApi.java:48)
```

I execute the tests in a terminal using the following Gradle command:

```
./gradlew --daemon test --info
```

UPD. I've added a print() to the request to see what is being sent/received:

```
org.myproject.api.TestProjectsApi > testAddProject STANDARD_OUT

    MockHttpServletRequest:
             HTTP Method = POST
             Request URI = /projects/
              Parameters = {}
                 Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json]}

                 Handler:
                    Type = org.myproject.api.ProjectsApi

                   Async:
           Async started = false
            Async result = null

      Resolved Exception:
                    Type = org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException

            ModelAndView:
               View name = null
                    View = null
                   Model = null

                FlashMap:

    MockHttpServletResponse:
                  Status = 415
           Error message = null
                 Headers = {Accept=[application/octet-stream, */*, text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1, */*, application/xml, text/xml, application/*+xml, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data]}
            Content type = null
                    Body = 
           Forwarded URL = null
          Redirected URL = null
                 Cookies = []
Gradle Test Executor 1 finished executing tests.
```

Comment: You are accepting `application/json; charset=UTF-8` but are sending `application/json`... Doesn't match., hence unsupported.

Comment: I've updated my code according to your suggestion, but it still does not work.

Comment: Are you sending the correct JSON?

Comment: Looks correct. I've added JSON input (in comments in the test). I've also added the definition of ProjectInput class.

Comment: You don't have a setter for the properties.

Comment: Added setters, but it didn't help.

Comment: Ensure that ProjectInput extends from Spring ResourceSupport and use the Spring Assembler to convert it to your own DTO (very easy to see when you debug, as Spring converters won't accept your own object)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had a similar case and I could solve it by adding both header-accept AND content-type.

```
Headers = {Accept=[application/json;charset=UTF-8], 
                   Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}
```

In the test module:

```
MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_JSON_UTF8 = new MediaType("application", "json", java.nio.charset.Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = post("/myPostPath");
request.content(json);
request.locale(Locale.JAPANESE);
request.accept(MEDIA_TYPE_JSON_UTF8);
request.contentType(MEDIA_TYPE_JSON_UTF8);
mockMvc.perform(request)
    .andDo(print())
    .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

First I only put `request.accept(..)`. But after adding `request.contentType(..)` it finally worked.

Comment: For me also, just added the ContentType when posting a list and the test now works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: this works fine, you can alse reference static member MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON in both accept(..) and contentType(..) directly no need to declare your own. wich is more prone to error

Answer (score 22):

I ran into this issue and was able to fix it by adding the @EnableWebMvc annotation to my test's SpringContext class.

Comment: To my big surprise this solved my problem. Weird but worked.

Comment: Yeah - I was surprised too! Nice when it's something simple, even if it seems weird.

Comment: This fixed my problem as well.  Does anyone know why/how this fixes it?

Comment: I didn't spend the time to dig into it, but "Adding this annotation to an @Configuration class imports the Spring MVC configuration from WebMvcConfigurationSupport" https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/EnableWebMvc.html

Answer (score 4):

Hello change your controller's method params  consumes and produces to:

```
consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
```

and your test case to

```
@Test
    public void testAddProject() throws Exception {
        ProjectInput input = new ProjectInput("name", "description");
        mockMvc.perform(post("/projects/")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(input)))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    }
```

EDIT:

The problem is in your `Project` class. Missing default constructor.

Comment: Fixed everything according to your suggestion, but it didn't help.

Comment: i missed the slash at the end of "projects" see edit

Comment: I added the slash at the end, but still have the same 415 error.

Comment: this is impossible, i tested your code and in my environment working as expected. Which import statements you are using? how you are running the test case? which is your IDE?

Comment: Hm... Interesting. I've added the information that you've requested to my question.

Comment: I'm executing the test with:
`./gradlew test --tests "SecurityTest.testProject"` where `SecurityTest` is my classname and `testProject` is my method name

Answer (score 0):

I was running into a similar issue - the issue for me was not setting the content type nor an issue with the JSON, rather that I did NOT have a JSON parser on the classpath. I realized that Spring wasn't including what I needed. Adding the Jackson databind (et al) jars to my build file resolved the issues

Answer (score -2):

I didn't have message converter bean in my applicationContext.xml.

I had to add the following to it:

```
<bean id="jacksonMessageConverter" `class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>`
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now everything works fine.

Comment: You don't need to register the converter manually.It should be registered by default if you have jackson libraries on the classpath and you use mvc:annotation-driven element in xml or @EnableWebMvc for Java config